# get error wcf when return data?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Drug> GetAll_Drug()
{
   List<Drug> obj_Lst_t;
   using (var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext())
  {
      obj_Lst_t = ctx.Drug.ToList();
  }
    return obj_Lst_t;
  }
```

**get Answer** [image]
 ------ but add OperationContract get error

debug
[image]
 get return data error
[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Where is it occurring? ...What do you want us to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your screen of stack trace

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException

So I believe this might be due to lazy loading or EF proxy serialization.

Try disabling the proxy.

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Drug> GetAll_Drug()
{
    List<Drug> obj_Lst_t;
    using (var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext())
    {
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; // disable proxy creation here.
        obj_Lst_t = ctx.Drug.ToList();
    }
    return obj_Lst_t;
}
```

Comment: tanks. why from OperationContract  GetAll_Drug not error?

Comment: @user1039134 Sorry! Did not get you what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

when return Data ctx dispose,
then obj_Lst_t value convert to null, 
or use :

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Drug> GetAll_Drug()
{
    List<Drug> obj_Lst_t;
    using (var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext())
    {
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 

foreach(var data in ctx.Drug)
       { obj_Lst_t.add(data);}
    }
    return obj_Lst_t;
}
```

or use:

```
 [OperationContract]
    public List<Drug> GetAll_Drug()
    {
        List<Drug> obj_Lst_t;
        using (var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext())
        {
            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 

    foreach(var data in ctx.Drug)
           { obj_Lst_t.add(new Drug{...});}
        }
        return obj_Lst_t;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following code error

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Patients> GetAll_Patients()
{
List<Patients> obj_Lst_t;
using (var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext())
{
ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
obj_Lst_t = ctx.Patients.ToList();
}
return obj_Lst_t;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yoe moust remove using,

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Drug> GetAll_Drug()
{
    List<Drug> obj_Lst_t;
   var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext();

        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 
        obj_Lst_t = ctx.Drug.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer and it is definitely not best practice to "just remove using" without explicitely disposing.